# DGML Background colour

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dgml

I have the following DGML, copied from the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn966108.aspx).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<DirectedGraph Title="DrivingTest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">  
   <Nodes>  
      <Node Id="Driver" Label="Student" Category="Person" />  
      <Node Id="Passenger" Label="Instructor" Category="Person" />  
      <Node Id="Car" Label="Car" Category="Automobile" />  
      <Node Id="Truck" Label="Truck" Category="Automobile" />  
   </Nodes>  
   <Links>  
      <Category Id="Person" Background="Orange" />  
      <Category Id="Automobile" Background="Yellow"/>  
      <Link Source="Driver" Target="Car" Label="Passed" Stroke="Black" Background="Green" Category="PassedTest" />  
      <Link Source="Driver" Target="Truck" Label="Failed" Stroke="Black" Background="Red" Category="PassedTest" />  
   </Links>  
</DirectedGraph>
```

When I open it in Visual Studio 2017 the colours are ignored.

[image: DGML is Visual Studio 2017]

Answer (score 1):

Categories should be within their own Categories tag like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<DirectedGraph Title="DrivingTest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">  
<Nodes>  
     <Node Id="Driver" Label="Student" Category="Person" />  
     <Node Id="Passenger" Label="Instructor" Category="Person" />  
     <Node Id="Car" Label="Car" Category="Automobile" />  
     <Node Id="Truck" Label="Truck" Category="Automobile" />  
</Nodes>  
<Links>
     <Link Source="Driver" Target="Car" Label="Passed" Stroke="Black" Background="Green" Category="PassedTest" />  
     <Link Source="Driver" Target="Truck" Label="Failed" Stroke="Black" Background="Red" Category="PassedTest" />  
</Links>  
<Categories>
     <Category Id="Person" Background="Orange" />  
     <Category Id="Automobile" Background="Yellow"/>  
</Categories>
</DirectedGraph>
```